# Convert 3 li & ul tags data from one div id to other div id with change of text to those 3 converted tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is my Original code below:

```
<div id="cp_listed">
    <span><b>Title</b></span>
</div>

<div class="bigright">
    <ul>
        <li id="cp_you_are" class=""><span>You are:</span> AAAA</li>
        <li id="cp_dept" class=""><span>Dept:</span> XXXX</li>
        <li id="cp_id_593" class=""><span>Section:</span> BBBB</li>
        <li id="cp_id_999" class=""><span>Area:</span> CCCC</li>
        <li id="cp_role" class=""><span>Role:</span> YYYY</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

***Original Output***

**Title**

- You are: AAAA
- Dept: XXXX
- Section: BBBB
- Area: CCCC
- Role: YYYY

***Expected Code***

```
<div id="cp_listed">
  <span><b>Title</b></span>
        <div id="cp_you_are">
            <span><b>Posted by:</b></span> AAAA
        </div>
        <div id="cp_id_593">
            <span><b>Posted by:</b></span> BBBB
        </div>
        <div id="cp_id_999">
            <span><b>Posted by:</b></span> CCCC
        </div>
</div>

<div class="bigright">
    <ul>
        <li id="cp_dept" class=""><span>Dept:</span> XXXX</li>
        <li id="cp_role" class=""><span>Role:</span> YYYY</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

***Expected Output***

**Title**
 **Posted by:** AAAA
**Posted by:** BBBB
**Posted by:** CCCC

- Dept: XXXX
- Role: YYYY

This is what i'm expecting to get. I want to extract or remove li & ul tags of **#cp_you_are**, **#cp_id_593** & **#cp_id_999** id's & shift those id's data into **#cp_listed** div tag by converting li & ul tags into div tags of those 3 id tags inside to the **#cp_listed** div tag as shown in Expected Code & Output.

Also its text must be changed from **You are,Section & Area** to **Posted by** to all 3 as shown in Expected Output

Anyone plz helpme..

Comment: Can you post what you've tried already?

Comment: I used this javascript, but this is working for only #cp_you_are. I want for #cp_you_are, #cp_id_593 & #cp_id_999 all 3 id's


<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var getli = $('.bigright #cp_you_are');
    $('.bigright #cp_you_are').remove(); 
    $creDiv = $('<div />').attr('id',getli.attr('id')).html(getli.html());
    $("#cp_listed").append($creDiv);
    $("#cp_you_are").children("span").html("<b>Posted by: </b>");
}); 
</script>

Comment: Can you add that to the question? That way it'll format better. But if this works for one div, why don't you just repeat it for the other divs.

Comment: I did it but its not working for all 3. Its working only for 1 tag that too which is present in last line of javascript